# Are atoms elementary?

Tags: particle-physics, atomic-physics, atoms

I'm reading wikipedia about [Real neutral particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_neutral_particle).

I know, there are many different particles discovered in the background of atom, which was ( Neutrons + Protons + Electrons ) before. For example, [Neutralino](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutralino), etcetera...

Finally, there was discovered Higgs boson.

I'm interesting, are atoms still such fundamental as its was presented before?

For example, two atoms of Plumbum. Once, hop, couple of very little "bosons"( or Neutralinos or Gluons ) are connected to one such atom. Will it emit something and stay as another one atom of Plumbum or it can be differ a little?

Can be such, that we have two peaces of Plumbum. But one of it will consist of atoms a little bit different, with such spice of Gluons or Bosons per atom...

Or we are not able to test this yet?

Comment: Atoms consist of bound states of other particles. No, they are not "elementary" and haven't been considered as such for about a century.

Comment: Are you asking if all lead (plumbum) atoms are **identical**? Obviously they aren't elementary.

Comment: Yeah, you are telling this exactly how I want, **identical**. Are all atoms of lead **identical**?

Comment: Two atoms of the same isotope are identical in all their physical properties.

Comment: You say that you are really asking if atoms are identical, but you've accepted an answer that doesn't address this.

Comment: I see, atoms are not identical, it consist of different small particles. And its can be differ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atoms are not truly fundamental.

In fact if you say,atoms are made of electrons,protons and neutrons which are fundamental particles,then also you are wrong.Protons and neutrons are not fundamental as they are composed of still *smaller* particles,quarks.

For more information see this link-https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model

Hope my answer helps!!

Answer (score 0):

Atoms are not elementary particles - they are made up of other known particles which are considered elementary such as quarks, electrons, and a host of force carriers, such as photons, w and z bosons, gluons and higgs bosons

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that Neutralinos are hypothesized particles, they are not discovered. Moreover, atom itself cannot emit Gluons - gluons are trasmitters of strong force acting between quarks - particles that form subatomic particles - neutrons, protons and other particles.

You wonder if all atoms of Plumbum are identical. The answer is no - they are identical only in the ground state (the state with the lowest energy), but as you know atoms consist of nucleus and electrons. And these electrons (as well as nucleus) can be excited due to external energy. The measure of excitation is energy level. If different atoms of Plumbum are on different energy levels, so they are not identical anymore.